# Why useEffect() didn't report the warning when it performed an unmounted component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I followed a `Reat.js` teching video by a YouTube uploarder `The Net Ninjia` [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gZD-Tvwfod2gaISzfRiP9d)

In this video, the author indecated a runtime warning:`Warning：Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.`

But according to the following code I can't reproduce this `waring`.My code works just fine.

So what happened to this following code? Is it because React.js updated something?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // const abortCont = new AbortController();
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => {
          // console.log(res);
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error('could not fetch data for some reason');
          } else {
            return res.json();
          }
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setData(res);
          setIsPending(false);
          setError(null);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }, 2000);
  }, [url]);
  return { data, isPending, error };
};

export default useFetch;
```

However, I followed the video, changed the code as below, it raised a `AbortError`.But according to the author, this error won't happen.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortCont = new AbortController();

    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch(url, { signal: abortCont.signal })
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error('could not fetch data for some reason');
          } else {
            return res.json();
          }
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setData(res);
          setIsPending(false);
          setError(null);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
            console.log(err.name);
          } else {
            setIsPending(false);
            setError(err.message);
          }
        });
    }, 2000);
    return () => abortCont.abort();
  }, [url]);
  return { data, isPending, error };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Comment: what version of React do you use?

Comment: @skyboyer the version for React is react@18.2.0

Comment: I know there was a decision to remove this warning in 18: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/82 but I did not know if this has been released yet. Looks like it has been.

Comment: @skyboyer Thank you.
I followed video use `AbortController()`  within `useEffect()` to fix the warning but it raised the error `AbortError`  but i don't know why. T_T

Comment: @skyboyer I checked the discussion you mentioned and found the reason. Thank again.
The React contributor just remove this warning in my suitation. But actually the risk for This warning still exist. `AbortController()` works well for my code.